# Global Exception Filter in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I just made a custom exception filter in ASP .NET for an application which handles API's.

I made it global by adding the below piece of code to the WebApiconfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new Filters.ExceptionFilter());      //Declaration of Exception Filter
        }
    }
```

But I was told today that the filter needs to be declared in global.asax. I tried adding this, but it didn't work.

How can I declare the exception filter in global.asax?

Comment: Is your `Register()` method called in the global.asax?

Comment: Who told you it needs to be declared in global.asax? Are you sure your global.asax isn't already utilizing this Register method? Look on the Application_Start event. What did you try adding, and what do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: @mason, No my register isn't in the global.asax. I finally got it to work an hour ago by using adding the following to the app_start: ```GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new Filters.ExceptionFilter());```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found about 2 solutions for the same, which I wasn't able to find anywhere online.

The best solution is to add your filter using the GlobalConfigutation method of the System.Web.Http namespace. I added the following line:

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new Filters.ExceptionFilter());`,
where Filter is a directory containing ExceptionFilter.cs.

Comment: Filter is *not* a directory containing ExceptionFilter.cs. In C#, we don't care about folders when it comes to class names. Instead, we care about [namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/). By default when you create a new C# file, the start of the namespace will match what your project is configured for, and any folders it's placed in will be appended to it as additional segments in the namespace. But  that's not required, and your namespace can be customized.